# Python join() method in loop

Tags: python, string, join

I am trying to use the join() method in a loop by adding each element one by one in an empty string ->

```
given = ['s','o','h','a','m']
res = ' '
for x in given:
    res = res.join(x)
print(res)
```

The resulting string is only ->

```
"m"
```

Although I know that I can join the list in one go using ->

`res.join(given)`

But I wanted to try this out in the loop.

Is it possible?

Comment: `join()` is actually designed to *not* add characters one by one.

Comment: What is `k`...?!

Comment: @deceze was a typo corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the line

```
res = res + x
```

as the loop body instead.

Comment: Very foolishly I wanted to use a function in a loop forgetting a basic syntax of just adding characters to a new string using the '+' operator.